# Finding duplicate blocks of text within a file using shell script

Tags: shell

Say I have a text file with the following lines:-

```
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

Now `abcd/efgh/a.jar` in the first case has `abcd/efgh/a.class`, `cdef/ghij/b.class` and `klmn/opqr/c.class` within the curly braces. Consider it as 1 block of text. Now `abcd/efgh/a.jar` below again has `cdef/ghij/b.class` within curly braces. I want to remove this section/block of text. So the final output needs to be like:-

```
abcd/efgh/a.jar
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
klmn/opqr/c.class
}
lkmn/opqr/b.zip
{
abcd/efgh/a.class
cdef/ghij/b.class
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing service. Please tell us what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: You should show us what you tried and how you failed so far. Don't expect us to develop your scripts for free please.

Comment: You giv an example, but do not actually describe the problem.  I suspect what you mean is that you want to consider the two blocks to be duplicates because they are each preceded by the same line of text (`abcd/efgh/a.jar`), but you haven't explained why you select the smaller of the two to be removed.  Is it because it appears later in the file?  Or because each of the lines in it appears in the previous block?  Or simply because it contains fewer lines?  Or perhaps because it is Tuesday and on Tuesday you always discard lines 12 to 16?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to build a state machine like this in `awk`, but this seems to do what it appears that you want:

```
 awk '/^{$/{s=1} /^}$/ {s=0} !p; !s{p=k[$0]++}'  input
```

(which is to say, it produces the demonstrated output for the sample input, but I'm making many assumptions about what you want for the general case.)